# Why do the mutant children need to reach Canada in Logan?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

In the movie *Logan*, why do the mutant children need to cross the border into Canada? What makes sure they won't be hunted by Transigen/the Reavers there?

Comment: Good lord, spoilers right up front.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite sorry i just didn't know how to do that 'reveal on touch' thingie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Why do the need to reach Canada?

Gabriela and Laura explain this in the movie. They believe a sanctuary called "Eden" exists, and that if they can reach the coordinates in North Dakota, that they will be granted passage to it.

Logan is skeptical, seeing as that Eden and the coordinates seem to come from an old issue of an *X-Men* comic. Still, upon arrival at the coordinates, we learn that there *is* some sort of sanctuary across the border, and that the refugee mutants will be granted access.

### Why do they believe they will be safe?

Because that's the rumor and story they've been told. A large theme of the movie is hope for the future and faith. Laura is largely taking it on faith that Eden is even real, never mind that they will be safe from persecution there.

### Will/would they actually be safe?

Since we never learn the true nature of Eden, or what defenses they have, we'll never really know for sure. However, Transigen and the Reavers clearly do not worry about legalities or borders, as they crossed the US-Mexico border in pursuit of Laura. It's unlikely that they'd care much about the US-Canada border either. If any Transigen or Reaver forces remain post-Logan, they would likely still pursue the refugees into Canada and Eden.

Comment: Not all national borders are created equally.

Comment: You're not wrong, but my point is that Transigen/the Reavers aren't exactly concerned with the legalities of magical borderlines between countries and may still continue to pursue if possible.

Comment: They may, but maybe Canada’s tougher on that sort of thing than Mexico.

Comment: Wasn't Eden that place in North Dakota where they reached? Also the Reavers were trying really hard to stop them from crossing so maybe there was something they were fearing?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite again, I'm still not sure how that contradicts anything I've said. Will they absolutely pursue? No. Is it possible/likely? Yes, depending on what the defenses actually are.

Comment: @PrakharMishra they reach the coordinates in North Dakota. They speak with someone in Eden over the radio and schedule passage.

Comment: I’m really just quibbling over “they crossed the US-Mexico border in pursuit of Laura... It's unlikely that they'd care much about the US-Canada border either”.You‘re stating equivalence of Mexico and Canada, without anything in particular from the movie to support it, and one reasonably big thing (the desire of the mutants to flee there) that at least suggests Eden is a different kettle of fish.

Comment: I got the impression, perhaps wrongly, that mutants would be under the protection of law enforcement in Canada, while in the US people hated mutants and the government turned a blind eye to illegal efforts to stop them.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but if the trip wasn't supposed to thematically echo the Underground Railroad, I'll eat my hat.

Answer (score 0):

The movie does not answer this directly, only by implication. In real life, a country would not permit a paramilitary force like Transgen to operate with impunity within its borders. It appears from the movie that Transigen can do just this. This is most likely because the future governments have some combination of being:

A. In league with Transigen

B. Corrupted by Transigen, bribed to turn a blind eye to their illegal activities

C. So consumed with hatred of mutants that they turn a blind eye to their illegal activities

D. Unable to stop Transigen because this is the type of dystopian future where the country is ruled by megacorporations like Transigen, with the government mostly a figurehead.

E. Unable to stop Transigen because they are weak and ineffective at maintaining law and order.

We can infer from the movie that one or more of these is true of the US and Mexico, but there is no particular reason to believe this is also true of Canada, and the implication is that it is not true - that Canada is still able to maintain law and order within its borders, and would attempt to meet any invasion by Transigen with police, military, and/or cyborg superhero forces. While the Reavers presumably could pursue the mutants into Canadian territory, they may choose not to because they fear being captured or killed, or perhaps Transigen has ordered them not to because it is likely to fail and they don't wish to lose their operatives and/or face sanctions from the Canadian government.